# "Mount error(13): Permission denied" What are the parse errors in my text?

Tags: mount, cifs

Bonjour/hello,

My /etc/fstab looks like this:

```
    # /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=4e7427c7-6df4-4fc3-92ae-d757d5f00139 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=70AD-311D  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1


//pdc.mio.osupytheas.fr/BIOINFO/    /home/emily/mount/bioinfo/ cifs 
credentials=/home/emily/.smbcredentials,noperm,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,iocharset=utf8,_netdev 
0 0 

//pdc.mio.osupytheas.fr/PHYCOVIR/   /home/emily/mount/PHYCOVIR/ cifs
credentials=/home/emily/.smbcredentials,noperm,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,iocharset=utf8,_netdev
0 0
```

I am getting:

```
    mount: /etc/fstab: parse error at line 15 -- ignored
mount: /etc/fstab: parse error at line 16 -- ignored
mount: /etc/fstab: parse error at line 19 -- ignored
mount: /etc/fstab: parse error at line 20 -- ignored
Password for root@//pdc.mio.osupytheas.fr/PHYCOVIR/:  ************
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

After I

```
 sudo mount "/home/emily/mount/PHYCOVIR/"
```

What am I doing incorrectly? Also thanks for any help, I apologise for the novice question - I am just very unsure here.

Comment: Each entry must be on a single line - you appear to have newlines before and after the credentials (making 3 lines instead of 1)

Comment: @steeldriver I have made the change, I am still receiving the same error number, however.